# Exception Save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transient

I have a User class and a Role class with ManyToMany relationship. I make its Daos and controller classes. I also made a JSP to register new roles and new users with associated roles.

When i access the user form, i can register the first user with your respective role, but when i am redirected to the user form again and try to save another user, it throws an exception like: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.eduardoportfolio.weblibrary.models.Role

what i am doing wrong?

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {
@Id
private String login;
@NotBlank
private String password;
@NotBlank
private String name;
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();


@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
@Id 
private String name;


@Controller
@Transactional
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RoleController {

@Autowired
RoleDao roleDao;

@RequestMapping("roleForm")
public ModelAndView roleForm(Role role){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user/roleForm");
    modelAndView.addObject("roleList", roleDao.list());
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="saveRole", method=RequestMethod.POST, name="saveRole")
public ModelAndView saveRole(@Valid Role role, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return roleForm(role);
    }
    roleDao.save(role);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "Role successfully 
registered");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/register/roleForm");
}

}


@Controller
@Transactional
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
UserDao userDao;
@Autowired
RoleDao roleDao;

@RequestMapping("userForm")
public ModelAndView userForm(User user) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user/userForm");
    modelAndView.addObject("roleList", roleDao.list());
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping (value="saveUser", method=RequestMethod.POST, name="saveUser")
public ModelAndView saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, 
                                                        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return userForm(user);
    }
    userDao.save(user);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", "User successfully registered");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/register/userForm");
}

}


@Repository
public class RoleDao {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager manager;

public void save(Role role){
    manager.persist(role);
}

public void delete(Role role){
    manager.remove(role);
}

public List<Role> list(){
    return manager.createQuery("select p from Role p", 
Role.class).getResultList();
}

}


@Repository
public class UserDao implements UserDetailsService {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws 
UsernameNotFoundException {

    String jpql = "select u from User u where u.login = :login";
    List<User> users = manager.createQuery(jpql, User.class) .setParameter("login", userName).getResultList();
    if(users.isEmpty()){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException ("The user "+ userName + "is not found !");
    }

    return users.get(0);
}

public void save(User user){
    user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
    manager.persist(user);
}

public void delete(User user){
    manager.remove(user);
}
}
```

Comment: The role that comes from the web request was built by your web framework, Spring MVC or whatever. It wasn't loaded from a database by Hibernate. So it's not attached. This is one of the many downsides of using the same class for both DAO and DTO: you can't easily tell which sort you're using in a given place. There are many ways out of this. I recommend reading up on MVVM and learning from that way of doing things, but ymmv.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Paul...I posted other Question, where i have found the real situation, and there has the link to the solution of my problem...Ufff

Comment: Here is the other Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497876/how-bind-checkboxes-with-a-model-object-list-resolved